# Find all solutions to $a+b+2c-d=3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Am I to solve this using matrices? I can't figure out how.

I was just using trial and error and got:

$a=b=c=d=1$

$a=b=1,   c=4,   d=3 $

etc (I got loads, it could go on forever?)

Is there a proper process to find these?
If not, is there a way to find how many solutions this equation has?
Right now I would say there were infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want all real solutions ($a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$) to

$$a+b+2c-d=3$$

then just solve the equation for any one of the variables:

$$d=a+b+2c-3.$$

The set of solutions is

$$\{(a,b,c,a+b+2c-3)\ | \ a,b,c \in\mathbb{R} \}$$

Answer (score 1):

It has infinity many solution.

Set $a,b,c$ arbitrary and calculate $d$ for a new answer!

---

More precisely  the answer of the equation has dimension $3$ which means you have $3$ degree of freedom to solve that...